# Can I create a subsection of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, feature-request

I'm an instructor teaching web development to adults. For their final projects, instead of coming to us with typos or other small issues, I'd like to set up a sub-section of Stack Overflow that would allow the other students to help each other, learn how to use Stack Overflow, and serve as a temporary knowledge base for the students.

This subsection would be private-ish where the other students can pop in and check to see if someone has already answered their question. It could be deactivated in 2-4 weeks when the course is over.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Not within the Stack Exchange network itself. I recall seeing a question somewhere about Stack Exchange clones- It might be possible to set one of those up to help you. Edit: You can find that list [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones) on MSE. I don't know for sure if it'll help you or not, but worth looking at.

Comment: Closely related on MSE: [Classroom specific Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86208) See also (something along these lines was done, but I don't know its fate): [What is story behind the edX Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231208)

Comment: You'd be better off setting up something like OSQA: http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/open-source-question-answer-software

Comment: As JonH, OSQA or perhaps [Shapado](http://shapado.com/) (where we moved iRosetta to (now defunc due to DNS non-renewal)). See *[Stack Exchange clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267)* for a wider selection.

Comment: *learn how to use Stack Overflow* - Just out of curiosity, will they actually be tested on this? Will they have to do something like create an MCVE from a set of bugged code?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the SUPER clear typo edits!

Comment: Thanks for the direction guys! I wish I could make @Kendra's answer the solution.

Answer (score 4):

To mind, there's no formal process that would allow you to do this.  The use case is narrow and one-time, so I don't think that Stack Exchange would be willing to invest the time into building something like this out.

You could likely accomplish what you really need with self-hosted forum software.

However, this line caught my attention:

> I'd like to set up a sub-section of Stack Overflow that would allow the other students to ..., learn how to use Stack Overflow...

That's the primary motivation behind [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  One learns general things about Stack Overflow, what is considered on and off topic, and what the various things around here mean.

If you were looking for something a bit deeper in terms of the nuances...that's a *lot* more than you could cover in just a month.  We've got users that have been around for years that assume different things of the system...and even I have some assumptions that may not be entirely accurate, and I've been around for almost five years at this point.